# How to write in memory data to DVD on Linux using C?

Tags: c, iso9660

I've data in MP4 format which needs to be copied to DVD on Linux platform. Now I am creating MP4 file on hard disk and then burning that file to DVD using growisofs command.
It would be more efficient if I didn't have to write the MP4 data to hard disk before they are burned to DVD. Please let me know if there is a way to write in memory data to DVD using C program.

Answer (score 0):

By reimplementing the tasks growisofs performs. DVDs are different to randomly accessible storage. First the data to be burnt onto the blank medium must be prepared into in a certain format, namely ISO9660, this includes a certain error correction scheme. The result of this is a complete **Track**. In the ISO9660 scheme it's not possible to record single files, only whole file systems. Once you got the FS you must implement the whole program for controlling the recording process.

This is what growisofs does. Now you could take the source of growisofs and replace the code it uses to read the files with code to read from some shared memory. But then you must make sure, that your program can deliver the data continously, without falling into pauses. Once started, the recording process should not be interrupted.

Anyway: If you're under Linux your program could provide the filesystem structure through FUSE.

Comment: How about USB flash drive? I use 'cp' command to copy from hard disk to USB flash drive. Can I directly open a file on USB flash drive using fopen() and write to it using fwrite()? Help on this would be appreciated.